# @ViewChild is undefined in mat-tab when it's not the first tab

Tags: angular

I have a component with a material tab group. I'm trying to access a child component on the 3 tab but the @viewChild is undefined. It works when it's in the first tab.

snippet from the component html:

```
<mat-tab-group>
  <mat-tab label="Person Details">
    <app-person-form [(form)]="personForm"></app-person-form>
  </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Addresses">
    <app-address-list [addresses]="person.addresses" [isForDelivery]="false" [selectedAddressIndex]="null"
      (addAddressClick)="addAddress()" (editAddressClick)="editAddress($event)"></app-address-list>
  </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Accounts">
    <app-person-account-member-list [roles]="person.accountRoles" (addAccountClicked)="addAccountClicked($event)"></app-person-account-member-list>
  </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Organisations">
    <app-person-organisation-member-list [roles]="person.organisationRoles"></app-person-organisation-member-list>
  </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Subscriptions">
    <app-person-delivery-list [deliveries]="person.deliveries" [addresses]="addresses"></app-person-delivery-list>
  </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab *ngIf="isDebug" label="DEBUG">
    <pre>
      {{value | json}}
    </pre>
  </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

ViewChild declaration in the component ts

```
@ViewChild(PersonAccountMemberListComponent) accountRolesList: PersonAccountMemberListComponent;
```

The PersonAccountMemberListComponent emit's an event, the parent component (with the tab group) reacts to it and based on the user's choice, I need to refresh the PersonAccountMemberListComponent component. I know it is fully rendered as the PersonAccountMemberListComponent triggers the cycle itself.
Everything works except refreshing the child as the @ViewChild reference is undefined

Comment: Are you sure that the components of the other tabs are already initialized?

Comment: app-person-account-member-list triggers the event by the user clicking a button in it so it has to be rendered.

Comment: it seems to be working now, not sure what made it work now. Didn't change anything as per the original question

Answer (score 1):

It would be better if any stackblitz created but i am suggesting below approach that would be helpful for you.
You can get the all tabs in MatTabGroup.
First create view child for tab group as below

```
<mat-tab-group #tab>
```

And
in TS file

```js
@ViewChild("tab", { static: false }) tab:MatTabGroup ;
```

Now you can access any tab data using `this.tab._tabs._results`